# SQL Server/C# - Storing big XML data in a column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have an XML string that may contain a huge amount of information. I plan to store it in a SQL Server database but I am not sure which is the best way to do so. Currently, I have 2 options:

1. Store the entire XML string in an nvarchar(max) column
2. Convert the XML string into a file, then convert that file into a byte array, then save that byte array in a varbinary(max) column

Out of the two, which is the best option in terms of memory efficiency and scalability? But if there are better options, I'm open to hear them all.

Comment: Store it as [XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: @DourHighArch I didn't know SQL had a type for XML! Thank you for this, it's going to be a very handy resource for me moving forward with my tinkering! :D

Comment: @DourHighArch will storing the xml data in an XML SQL datatype have any problems in the future when there are millions of transactions being saved as opposed to having an nvarchar or varbinary?

Comment: Why should there be any difference in the space these two options take?

Comment: You can also parse the xml into tables and columns.